# Jquery load url with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to automatically run an ajax url when my page is fully loaded using `.load()` function. It seems my code doesn't work.

Other information:

- The code is used for tracking affiliate users and is provided on the website for merchant users
- I'm not sure of the `jquery` version but I know my version doesn't accept `$`, but only `jQuery`

The code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=xxxxx"
    });
});
```

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your own website? Otherwise it may be a cross domain issue (designed to stop people embedding other people's web content) :) If that is not your website you would need to scrape their data from your web server instead (tut tut) :>

Comment: @GoneCoding it's a piece of code use for tracking affiliate users on that website. no it's not mine but this code is provided on the website for merchant users

Comment: Could also be because `.load()` was remove in JQuery v3. What version are you using?

Comment: That URL just returns a stock 1x1 pixel image to me (and I don't mean stock as in shares). Does their site require you to register the domain it will be used on with them?

Comment: your url returns this in return to me when i checked.
https://shareasale.com/siteimages/1x1.png

Comment: That makes sense as OP states it's a tracking URL

Comment: So why load it via ajax? Surely a tracking image should just be referenced in the page *as an image*?

Comment: @Turnip i can't check the version of my jquery right now. all I know is my version doesn't accept `$` , but only `jQuery`

Comment: Unless you are on pre-v1.8 you should be using `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });`

Comment: @GoneCoding because I'm trying to load the `url`, i'm not sure if i can load the url itself alone inside the `.load()`

Comment: @Lynerd: My point is why do you need to load a tracking pixel via Ajax at all? I used to work in SEO and we would just include the link to the tracking pixel via `<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748" width="1" height="1">`. Then no cross domain issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really puzzled why you need to load a tracking pixel via Ajax:

I used to work in SEO and we would just include the link to the tracking pixel in an image e.g. via

`<img src="https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748" width="1" height="1">`.

Then you have no cross domain issues, no ajax, no worries.It just records on their site that the page loaded has your affiliate code (and probably drops a cookie at the same time).

Comment: I'm sorry if you got confused, seriously I also don't know, I just tried to use ajax to call the url. sorry I'm just a newbie

Comment: sir, how can i load the image containing the link? should i use javascript?

Comment: See above... just reference the URL in an image in the page somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely working but just shows this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

This might not work from yout local host but will work properly from any server.

And still there is any error try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
           url:'https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748',
           success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the error in your browser console

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://shareasale.com/sale.cfm?amount=99.00&tracking=15&transtype=sale&merchantID=49748. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).